# Lattice-like structure with maximum spacing between vertices

Tags: graph-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, lattices, sphere-packing

I'll first describe my problem in layman's terms. I have a map with $m$ countries and I want to color each country with a different color (this has nothing to do with the 4-color theorem). How do I choose the colors so as to maximize contrasts?

Each color is a 3D vector in the unit cube. I want the minimum distance between any two of these vectors, to be maximum. What is the 3D lattice that accomplishes this goal, that is, maximizing the minimum distances between vertices?

This is related to crystal structures. If the minimum distance between atoms/molecules/ions in a crystal, is maximum, maybe the crystal is more resistant against compression. Maybe diamond crystals achieve this, I don't know. Or you can view it as a graph theory problem: finding a graph where the minimum distances between nodes, is maximum. (as a side question, is this an NP-hard problem?)

Comment: In two dimensions, if $m=3$ the points are the vertices of an equilateral triangle of side $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}$. In 3D, if $m=4$, the points are the vertices of a regular tetrahedron of side $\sqrt{2}$ (see http://people.missouristate.edu/lesreid/pow08_98.html). Example of color set corresponding to this is {black, yellow, purple, cyan}.

Comment: If you really have a map or graph, maybe the contrast should matter only for neighbors rather than all pairs?

Comment: @RobPratt: I mentioned maps, but in fact what I am coloring is the clusters resulting from a clustering algorithm. They have a very complicated topology (cluster A might have a portion inside cluster B and another one outside B;  the issue is having a nice set of 10 colors when you have 10 clusters, the color playing the role of a label, for instance if you include the figure in a publication).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No proof of optimality, but here are conjectured values for $m \le 10$ based on numerical optimization:
\begin{matrix}
m & \text{maximin?} \\
\hline
2 & \sqrt{3} \\
3 & \sqrt{2} \\
4 & \sqrt{2} \\
5 & \sqrt{5}/2 \\
6 & 3\sqrt{2}/4 \\
7 & 1.0010898245 \\
8 & 1 \\
9 & \sqrt{3}/2 \\
10 & 3/4 \\
\end{matrix}

```
m = 2:
1 1 1 
0 0 0 

m = 3:
1 0 1 
0 1 1 
0 0 0 
    
m = 4:
0 1 1 
1 1 0 
1 0 1 
0 0 0 
    
m = 5:
1.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.5 
0.5 1.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 1.0 
1.0 0.5 1.0 

m = 6:
0.25 0.00 0.00 
0.00 1.00 0.25 
0.75 1.00 1.00 
1.00 0.75 0.00 
0.00 0.25 1.00 
1.00 0.00 0.75 

m = 7:
0.292123 1.000000 1.000000 
0.033021 1.000000 0.033021 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.033021 0.033021 1.000000 
1.000000 0.033021 0.033021 
1.000000 0.292123 1.000000 
1.000000 1.000000 0.292123 

m = 8:
0 0 0 
0 1 0 
0 1 1 
1 0 1 
0 0 1 
1 1 0 
1 1 1 
1 0 0 
    
m = 9:
1.0 1.0 1.0 
1.0 0.0 1.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 1.0 
1.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 0.0 
1.0 1.0 0.0 
0.0 1.0 1.0 
0.5 0.5 0.5 
    
m = 10:
1.00 0.25 1.00 
0.50 0.75 0.50 
0.00 1.00 0.00 
1.00 1.00 0.00 
0.00 0.25 1.00 
0.00 0.25 0.00 
0.50 0.00 0.50 
0.00 1.00 1.00 
1.00 1.00 1.00 
1.00 0.25 0.00
```

Comment: Nice table. Wondering about the asymptotic behavior. It could also be extended to 4D but I am only interested in 3D.

Comment: Would you mind posting the vertices for the (conjectured) optima? I plan to use it for real in my coloring problem. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention in 3D if $m=4$, the other solution (I don't think there are more than two), besides {black, yellow, purple, cyan}, is {white, red, green, blue}. The latter is visually more pleasant.